# iOS: Custom product page

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

In our application, we want to know through which custom product page the user installed the application, but I’m not sure about the flow because I don’t have a way to test it without releasing a version (or is there a way?)

I generate an access token to access the Search Ads API.

Using `AAAttribution.attributionToken()`, I make a request to https://api-adservices.apple.com/api/v1/ and expect to receive a conversion.

I make a request to [https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v4/campaigns/\(conversion.campaignId)](https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v4/campaigns/%5C(conversion.campaignId)) to get the campaign.

I make a request to [https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v4/apps/\(campaign.adamId)/product-pages/](https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v4/apps/%5C(campaign.adamId)/product-pages/) and expect to receive a product page.

**What is the best practice to do? On client side executing only https://api-adservices.apple.com/api/v1/ and sending the result to the server that will continue with the others API’s?**

Is the flow correct? How did you do it? Is there a way to test it without releasing a version to the store?